# Garmin, trying to add ActivityExtension to the TrainingCenterDatabase. Create TCX File

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, garmin

I'm trying to build a converter for daum Ergometer csv files to tcx.

The final goal is to be able to upload the data to the garmin connect.

So I was able to generate class from

https://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd

and was able to upload it however I wasn't able to add Watts and Speed ... so I looked more into it and found the part ... Extensions ... https://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtensionv2.xsd counting one and one together I started trying to merge those schemas to achieve my goal ... however in the end I was able to create a manually adjusted xml which gave me the result I was looking for ... but didn't achieve to generate an approprite class maybee someone could help me ...

The final xml should look similar to this one ... how can I generate the class I need for it .... or how can I achieve this xml by using the mentioned schemas from above ... TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd & ActivityExtensionv2.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
<TrainingCenterDatabase 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2" 
    xmlns:ns3="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2" 
    xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Activities>
        <Activity Sport="Biking">
            <Id>2016-08-11T19:59:08.6122923Z</Id>
            <Lap StartTime="2016-08-11T19:57:48.6122923Z">
                <TotalTimeSeconds>80</TotalTimeSeconds>
                <DistanceMeters>225</DistanceMeters>
                <MaximumSpeed>7.5</MaximumSpeed>
                <Calories>0</Calories>
                <AverageHeartRateBpm>
                    <Value>84</Value>
                </AverageHeartRateBpm>
                <MaximumHeartRateBpm>
                    <Value>93</Value>
                </MaximumHeartRateBpm>
                <Intensity>Active</Intensity>
                <Cadence>31</Cadence>
                <TriggerMethod>Manual</TriggerMethod>
                <Track>
                    <Trackpoint>
                        <Time>2016-08-11T19:57:49.6122923Z</Time>
                        <DistanceMeters>0</DistanceMeters>
                        <HeartRateBpm>
                            <Value>59</Value>
                        </HeartRateBpm>
                        <Cadence>3</Cadence>
                        <Extensions>
                            <ns3:TPX>
                                <ns3:Speed>0.27777777777777785</ns3:Speed>
                                <ns3:Watts>20</ns3:Watts>
                            </ns3:TPX>
                        </Extensions>
                    </Trackpoint>
                </Track>
                <Extensions>
                    <ns3:LX>
                        <ns3:MaxBikeCadence>76</ns3:MaxBikeCadence>
                    </ns3:LX>
                    <ns3:LX>
                        <ns3:AvgSpeed>3.0538194444444451</ns3:AvgSpeed>
                    </ns3:LX>
                    <ns3:LX>
                        <ns3:AvgWatts>20</ns3:AvgWatts>
                    </ns3:LX>
                    <ns3:LX>
                        <ns3:MaxWatts>20</ns3:MaxWatts>
                    </ns3:LX>
                </Extensions>
            </Lap>
        </Activity>
    </Activities>
</TrainingCenterDatabase>
```